# How can I send English text and get a German audio file return?

Tags: google-api, google-translate, playback

What works on the website: Input a text phrase ("I wish you a Merry Christmas") and get back spoken German voice saying "Ich wünsche Ihnen Frohe Weihnachten".

(How) can this be achieved with the API, getting back an *.MP4 file?

Comment: Someone posted this, but it seems not to work as described (rather, the reading speed is increased after double-clicking the loudspeaker icon):

"How do I get Google translate to audio?

To download audio from Google Translate, follow these steps:
Go to the Google Translate website.
Write text to convert.
Press the F12 button.
Go to the Network tab.
Click on the volume button to play the audio.
Double-click on this link.
Download audio from Google Translate using the browser."

Answer (score 0):

The `Translate API` basically receives some text content and returns you another text content in the translated language.
If you need to get an audio file with speaking content you should try the `Text-to-Speech API`.

As you can try [here](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech), with the Text-to-Speech API you can send a text content and some options like the language of the text, voice type, speed and some others. In this [page](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/samples) you can find some samples and tutorials about how to use the API.